# Create xml file with XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps, xmlwriter

I am having problems with the Create method in XmlWriter.

Even when i use the example from msdn, it will not work.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcsse48t.aspx

I have created a "Blank page" project, for a windows store app.
In it, ive inserted the example code from msdn, to test how the XmlWriter class works.

VS gives me the error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'Create(string)', candidates are: 
System.Xml.XmlWriter Create(System.IO.Stream) (in class XmlWriter)
System.Xml.XmlWriter Create(System.IO.TextWriter) (in class XmlWriter)
System.Xml.XmlWriter Create(System.Text.StringBuilder) (in class XmlWriter)
System.Xml.XmlWriter Create(System.Xml.XmlWriter) (in class XmlWriter)
```

This works without a problem in a console application. But i need to make a windows store app.

What i wish to end up doing, is adding to an existing xml file.

Can someone tell me why this does not work, or how to reach my goal in a different way.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:

Sorry, my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace DatabaseTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button_submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("book");
                writer.WriteElementString("price", "19.95");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and full error message

Comment: Sorry, added my code.

Comment: My crystal ball told that you probably forgot to add `using System.Xml;`

Comment: He seems to have several candidates, there is a conflict. Show your using statements and the entire error message.

Comment: There's actually nothing wrong with `using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"))`, I have ran a sample console application using it now. Are you missing a reference as @Reniuz mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. And sorry for the lacking information.
It is my first post.
I have now added the entire code of my project.

Should this only work with console apps?

Comment: There is mystery here. Can you add screen shot of your code, and build error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Windows Store App, isn't it? Edit your question tags and try this:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("output.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
  System.IO.Stream s =  writeStream.AsStreamForWrite();
  System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
  settings.Async = true;
  using (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(s, settings))
  {
    // Do stuff...

    await writer.FlushAsync();
  }
}
```

You can remove namespaces qualifiers once you know it works.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx) to learn about how to store files in Windows Store Apps. Also take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx) for samples. My code will use the Local App Folder, i.e. something like: `C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Packages\[appName]\LocalState\`

Comment: Yes. It is a windows store app. Ive only used c# for a month or so, so i didnt know it made a difference. Also, your solution seems to work. However, no file shows up.
In the `code`//do stuff `code` area, i put in the `code`writer.WriteStartElement`code` stuff from the msdn example

Comment: The file will be stored in your local storage folder, e.g. "C:\Users\\[name]\AppData\Local\Packages\\[appName]\LocalState\"

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a link about file storage in Windows Store Apps.

Comment: It is not there, at all.
A friend just told me that it is not possible to save xml files to the root folder. And linked me to info on the StorageFolder class. I assume i will make your code work, when i fix the location it is saved. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MortenToudahl I made a mistake in my previous comment regarding the file location. I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful,

```
 using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("employees.xml"))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");

        foreach (Employee employee in employees)
        {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Employee");

        writer.WriteElementString("ID", employee.Id.ToString());   // <-- These are new
        writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", employee.FirstName);
        writer.WriteElementString("LastName", employee.LastName);
        writer.WriteElementString("Salary", employee.Salary.ToString());

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestiong. However, this gives me the exact same result. Are you testing in a console application?

Comment: Yes, and it runs smoothly in console application , try using this, XmlTextWriter w = new XmlTextWriter("test.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
w.WriteStartElement("root");
w.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "x");
w.WriteStartElement("item1");
w.WriteEndElement();
w.WriteStartElement("item2");
w.WriteEndElement();              or use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615574/windows-8-store-app-xmlwriter-does-not-write-anything-to-file

Comment: answer provided by Patrice Gahide is absolutely right

Answer (score 1):

Try to use inside your button_submit_Click method  a little bit changed like this without [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).Works for me:

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"));
writer.WriteStartElement("book");
writer.WriteElementString("price", "19.95");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.Flush();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestiong. However, this gives me the exact same result. Are you testing in a console application?

Comment: Nope .Let me try plz and i'll tell you

Comment: I tried a console app and the build is ok.What is your framework?Visual studio?

Comment: Visual studio ultimate 2013 with resharper 8

Comment: My entire MainPage codebehind file is in my original post. Cant you get it from there?

Comment: Yes. MainPage.xaml - it contains a button

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote: *I have created a "Blank page" **project, for a windows store app***.
The problem is that method is not supported in **Portable Class Library .NET for Windows Store apps**. If you compare [Create(Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x972ksd0(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Create(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcsse48t(v=vs.110).aspx) version information in documentation you'll see that Create(string) is not supported in your selected framework.

Comment: Can i rectify this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, got to the <kbd>View</kbd> menu and choose <kbd>Object Browser</kbd>.

Look for `System.Xml` in the left hand pane, and navigate the following

```
1. System.Xml
    - System.Xml
       - XmlWriter
```

Now click on `XmlWriter` and the right pane will show all the methods for that type. Look for the `Create` method and see what overloads are available. You should see `Create(string)`, like I do. If not, then quite honestly I'm not sure what's happening here. It could be that you're using a different .NET Framework like Portable Class Library or something???

EDIT:

You could just use

`using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml", new XmlWriterSettings()))`

so at least you can carry on your work.

Comment: Actually, i dont see a Create(String). I have .net 4.5 and 4.5.1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml", new XmlWriterSettings()))` gives the same error as my original code